# Obtener ubicación en versiones Android >=8

Tags: android, android-intent, servicio, geolocalización

Estoy desarrollando una app con android-studio para obtener con frecuencia la ubicación de dispositivos. El caso es que probando la app en dispositvos a partir de Android 8 o superior es cuando me da este error (en versiones anteriores no da problema):

```
2019-04-12 00:47:15.372 26573-26573/com.example.kakao E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.kakao, PID: 26573
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.kakao.LocationUpdatesService@c4a4e87 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.getBooleanExtra(java.lang.String, boolean)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3744)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1880)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:450)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.getBooleanExtra(java.lang.String, boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.kakao.LocationUpdatesService.onStartCommand(LocationUpdatesService.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3718)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1880) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:450) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

He estado leyendo los limites de ubicación en segundo plano para la versión 8 de la documentación y utilizo el servicio en primer plano como dice. El método obsoleto de startServiceInForeground queda descartado. Me estoy basando en el ejemplo de Google [Ejemplo de Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService).

El error me lo da en esta línea:
`boolean startedFromNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION, false);`
Cualquier ayuda me va a venir bien.

Comment: según entiendo, tu variable `intent` es `null` en ese momento. El mensaje de error dice básicamente que no puedes invocar el método `getBooleanExtra` sobre una referencia que está en `null`.

Comment: Correcto, pero solo lo hace en dispositivos >= android 8. En Lollipop, Marshmallow y Nougat no da error.

Comment: Claro, pero la pregunta es distinta, entonces. ¿Por qué tu intent en esas versiones está en null? Eso, porque si el intent está asignado, no verás el mismo error.